Need help understand phase shift control in SPS dual active bridge converter
I am trying to understand the control scheme of the phase shift controller in a dual active bridge (DAB) converter. I initially started with the built in PLECS DAB converter and understood all the control measures until I got to the phase shift controller and I got a bit confused. This is the controller in question:

It can be seen that the phase shift controller uses voltage feedback to control the phase of the switching gates. While the phase shift control circuit is intuitive, I don't understand how this works in a theoretical sense. I have tried reading various research papers to find equations that explain this, but haven't found anything helpful.
I tried to check out Simulink's built in DAB controller as well. It made more sense to me, but when I came to the function for gate controls, I met a function which seemed similar to that of the equivalent circuit of PLECS, but I still can't understand it.

I would really appreciate help on understanding these schemes/functions.

I have taken some time to understand this…here is my understanding.
The first part of the function ((u(1)+1)*0.5) is used to transform the bipolar sawtooth carriers (both on and off carriers) into  unipolar carriers. Since these carriers are the first input signals to the MUX block, they are represented as u (1) in the function block. You can confirm this by a simple model shown below:

The second part of the function (0.5±u(2)/720) is used to manipulate the phase shift angle signal. Since the phase shift signal is the second input to the MUX block, it is represented as u (2) in the function block. The two function blocks on the top are applied to the High voltage (HV) bridge while the other two function blocks on the bottom are applied to the LV bridge. In phase shift modulation, both the HV and LV bridges are initially operated at 0.5 duty ratio to obtain AC square waves at both sides of the transformer.
To understand a division by 720 consider this: The phase shift angle from the PI controller is first to be normalized through a division by 360°. This means the signal will be in the range of 0 to 1. But since the original duty ratio is in the range 0 to 0.5, the normalized signal is further divided by 0.5 to map it to this range. A division by 360 and further by 0.5 is same as dividing by 720.
This normalized phase shift angle signal is then added to 0.5 for the HV bridge while it is subtracted from 0.5 for the LV bridge. And this is just to manipulate the original Duty of 0.5 so as the two bridges are operated at different Duty ratio to achieve power transfer in the desired direction.
The hit zero crossing detection blocks and the latch (SR flip flops) consist of the logic circuit used to obtain the gate pulses from the phase shifted sawtooth carriers.
